# script works in one page not another

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I have two DropDownList. I fill the second one when the selected item of first one get changed.
I used jquery to do it.
it works in my create Page, but in another page (that is edit page) it doesnt call action method in controller.

```
        <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Province" class="control-label"></label>
                        <select asp-for="Province" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Province" 
                                new { id="provinces" , onchange="FillCity()" }></select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="City" class="control-label"></label>
                        <select asp-for="City" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.City"
                                new { id="cities" } ></select>
                    </div>
</div>
    
        @section Scripts {
            <script>
                function FillCity() {
                    var provinceId = $("#provinces").val();
    alert(provinceId);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "FillCity?provinceId=" + provinceId,
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json",               
                        success: function (data) {
                            $("#cities").html(""); // clear before appending new list
                            $.each(data, function (key, city) {
                                $("#cities").append(
                                    '<option value="' + city['id'] + '">'
                                    + city['name'] +
                                    '</option>');
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            </script>
            }
```

and this is my action in controller

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult FillCity( int provinceId)
        {
            var cities = _context.City.Where(i => i.ProvinceId == provinceId).Select(i => new { i.Id, i.Name });
            return Json(cities);
        }
```

the alert message get appear in edit page but action doesn't call,
why it works in one page not another?

Comment: Add the code where you call the `FillCity` on the page

Comment: @max I added that

Answer (score 1):

> UPDATE 29/07

```
@section Scripts {
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function FillCity() {
        var provinceId = $("#provinces").val();
        alert(provinceId);
        $.ajax({
            url: "FillCity?provinceId=" + provinceId,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#cities").html(""); // clear before appending new list
                $.each(data, function (key, city) {
                    $("#cities").append(
                        '<option value="' + city['id'] + '">'
                        + city['name'] +
                        '</option>');
                });
            }
        });
    }
</script>
}
```

---

I think the main reason is related with url path `FillCity`.

Change to `[HttpGet("/FillCity")]` to response ajax request `url: "FillCity?provinceId=" + provinceId`.

**Codes of Controller**

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["Province"] = new SelectList(_context.Province, "Id", "Name");
        ViewData["City"] = new SelectList(_context.City.Where(i => i.ProvinceId == _context.Province.FirstOrDefault().Id).Select(i => new { i.Id, i.Name }), "Id", "Name");

        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet("/FillCity")]
    public ActionResult FillCity(int provinceId)
    {
        var cities = _context.City.Where(i => i.ProvinceId == provinceId).Select(i => new { i.Id, i.Name });

        return Json(cities);
    }
```

**Codes of View is same as yours.**

> Sceenshots

[image]

If still not working in your case, please provide more debugging information so that we can help u out.

Press `F12` to open debug window in your Browser.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I don't know why ,but today it worked, I just changed style of page

Comment: If so, it might related with your JQuery.js import. If jquery import failed, the  $.ajax won't work well.

Comment: F12 is important tools to front-end dev.  It is very recommended that you try it. It can greatly improve your programming skills.

Comment: but this code doesnt work for the first value, I  mean when I open the page I select some value in my controller, but it doesnt fire the onchnage event, do you know why?

Comment: It must occurs JQuery error. Press F12 and click the "Console" tab to get the error info.

Comment: I checked but there is no error, i think this event doesn't get fired

Comment: alert(provinceId);                  Did this alert dialog show up or not?

Comment: for the first time that page loaded, alert dialog did not show up

Comment: That's weird. If so, your JavaScripts doesn't excute at all.

Comment: Compare with two pages carefully  to find out why js not excute.

Comment: thank you for your time, but for your page when the page get loaded the dialog didnt show up until you change the selected value

Comment: That's true. FillCity() only excuted when selected value changed not loaded.